# Proof verification problem

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, asymptotics

I would like to know what is the true output, and what is the way of solving it? To me, I have got solution to be exact as Q1.

> 1. Consider the following “proof” that 
>      $$
>    1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k\in O(n ^{k+1}).
>    $$
>      *proof.* Let $f(n)=1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k$ and $g(n)=n^{k+1}$. Then we have that
>      $$
>    \eqalign{
>    \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} & =
>    \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+n^k}{n^{k+1}} \\
>    & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{1^k}{n^{k+1}}+\dfrac{2^k}{n^{k+1}}+\dfrac{3^k}{n^{k+1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{n^k}{n^{k+1}}\right] \\
>    & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1^k}{n^{k+1}}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{2^k}{n^{k+1}}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{3^k}{n^{k+1}}+\cdots+\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^k}{n^{k+1}}
>    \\
>    &=0+0+0+\cdots+0 \\&=0.
>    }
>    $$
>
> Therefore, $f(n)\in O(g(n))$.
>  
>   $\qquad$ (a) The proof is wrong: run through the proof for $k-1$ and indicate why it fails. 
>   $\qquad$ (b) Prove (using the definition) that $$1^k+2^k+\cdots+n^k\in O(n^{k+1}).$$

Comment: What do you mean by "exact as Q1"?

Comment: are you perhaps mixing big O and little o notation?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use calculus, use the fact that
$$\int_2^{n + 1} {{{(x - 1)}^k}dx}  \leqslant {1^k} + {2^k} +  \cdots  + {n^k} \leqslant \int_1^{n + 1} {{x^k}dx} $$

(since function $x^k$ is increasing) to get limits that clearly show the order of the sum.